# Null pointer exception in Spring dao, dependency injection using bean configuration

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception

I am getting the following exception when I tried using auto-wired bean (Dependency injection using Setter Method and XML configuration)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ecms.controller.service.JobCreationServiceCMODImpl.txSaveData(JobCreationServiceCMODImpl.java:483)
at com.ecms.controller.action.CMODJobCreationAction.doSave(CMODJobCreationAction.java:440)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

**ezm-application.xml:**

```
   <bean>
    <bean id="cmodJobCreationDao" class="com.ecms.controller.dao.CMODJobCreationDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="jobCreationServiceCMOD" class="com.ecms.controller.service.JobCreationServiceCMODImpl">
    <property name="cmodJobCreationDao">
        <ref bean="cmodJobCreationDao" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

**JobCreationServiceCMODImpl:**

```
public class JobCreationServiceCMODImpl implements JobCreationServiceCMOD{
    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 430594221158425380L;
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(JobCreationServiceCMODImpl.class);
    private CMODJobCreationDao cmodJobCreationDao;

    …..
    /**
     * @return the cmodJobCreationDao
     */
    public CMODJobCreationDao getCmodJobCreationDao() {
        return cmodJobCreationDao;
    }

    /**
     * @param cmodJobCreationDao the cmodJobCreationDao to set
     */
    public void setCmodJobCreationDao(CMODJobCreationDao cmodJobCreationDao) {
        this.cmodJobCreationDao = cmodJobCreationDao;
    }

           public void txSaveData(JobCreationViewCMOD entity) throws Exception {
           JobCreationCMOD creation = new JobCreationCMOD();
        creation.setSrcFolder(entity.getSourceFolder());
        creation.setSrcApplicationGroup(entity.getApplicationGroup());
        creation.setSrcApplication(entity.getApplication());    
           cmodJobCreationDao.persistObject(creation);
           ..
```

**CMODJobCreationDaoImpl:**

```
public class CMODJobCreationDaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl implements CMODJobCreationDao {

    static String query = "From JobCreationCMOD Where JOBID=?";

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.ecms.controller.dao.ProfileCreationDao#fetchRepParam(java.lang.Integer)
     */
    public List<RepositoryParam> fetchRepParams(Integer id) {
        return find(query, new Object[] { id });
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess in your `CMODJobCreationAction` you construct a new instance of your `JobCreationServiceCMODImpl`. Use the one from the application context.

Answer (score 0):

Here your framework is unaware of cmodJobCreationDao object.
`cmodJobCreationDao.persistObject(creation);`

if you are using annotation based spring configuration then you can either autowire

```
@Autowired
private CMODJobCreationDao cmodJobCreationDao;
```

or in your method you can follow the following steps in txSaveData method:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Your xml path");

cmodJobCreationDao = (CMODJobCreationDao) ctx.getBean("cmodJobCreationDao");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see the stacktrace

```
      at com.ecms.controller.service.JobCreationServiceCMODImpl.txSaveData(JobCreationServiceCMODImpl.java:483)
      at com.ecms.controller.action.CMODJobCreationAction.doSave(CMODJobCreationAction.java:440)
```

You see that CMODJobCreationAction.doSave invoke JobCreationServiceCMODImpl.txSaveData, and I´m pretty sure that JobCreationViewCMOD is null. Debug and check why this value is null, maybe you need to pass this bean definition in the bean definition of CMODJobCreationAction. In any case I´m pretty sure that the exception is in this line creation.setSrcFolder(entity.getSourceFolder()); because like I said entity is null